# Kindly explain why in following example the output is 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Why the value of outcome is 'undefined' in the following example? Kindly explain someone how is this calculated?

```html
<script>
var foo = {
  bar: function() { return this.baz; },
  baz: 1
};

var a = (function(){
  return typeof arguments[0]();
})(foo.bar);

console.log(a);
</script>
```

> Note: I've been through following link and it doesn't explain this
>   example. There is no constructor function here ...
>   [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Don't post the same question [over again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879056/why-output-of-following-example-is-undefined-and-how-is-it-calculated) - this is indeed a dupe of that canonical. `arguments[0]()` invokes whatever function's within `arguments[0]` without a calling context. Like I said in the comment on that question, to retain the calling context, either pass `() => foo.bar()` or use `.bind`

Comment: @CertainPerformance [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) would be a better dupe target, imho...

Comment: `this` in `bar` refers `arguments` object of `a` when you call `bar` like `arguments[0]()` from `a`. Notice, that `arguments` is an object, not an array. See [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbuaty19/).

Comment: Use this code `return typeof ( arguments[0].call(foo) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arguments[0]()` is executing in the [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) context, but it does not have any object property defined in the name *bar* (which is a property of *foo*). This is why you get `undefined`. To solve the issue, you can bind the object.

Change

```
foo.bar
```

To

```
foo.bar.bind(foo)
```

```js
var foo = {
  bar: function() { return this.baz; },
  baz: 1
};
var a = (function(){
  console.log(this.constructor.name); // Window
  return typeof arguments[0]();
})(foo.bar.bind(foo));

console.log(a);
```

Comment: _"Kindly **explain** why in following..."_

Comment: can you please tell what does arguments[0] here is referring to? either -- foo.bar or returned value '1'? or whatever?

Comment: @Deadpool, `arguments[0]` refers to the function which you are passing to the function.

Comment: @Mamun - it refers to the function or the argument that we are passing in the function??? (like if we passed name, age as arguments in foo.bar???)

Comment: @Deadpool, it will refer what you pass to the function as parameter.

Comment: "_`arguments[0]()` is executing in the Window context_" No, it isn't. It is executed in the context of `arguments` object of `a`, because the passed function reference becomes a property of the arguments object.